# Notify on Super User review queues

Tags: discussion, review, notifications, apple

Is there any solution to notify my iOS devices that new items are populating the review queues?

Comment: I wonder if this is actually meta Stack Exchange or non-meta superuser.com. 

Comment: This is the right place.

Comment: Just noticed and remembered there is https://meta.stackexchange.com, sure isn't there better?

Comment: In general, how to get stuff done on SE sites would be appropriate for a meta site rather than the main site.  Meta SE mainly focuses on meta questions common to all sites or groups of sites.  The site-specific Metas focus on meta questions specific to that site, or at least where the member is specifically interested in only that site.  If the iOS notification is a feature of the SE infrastructure, you could get an answer on Meta SE, or either Meta SU (since it's about accessing SU information), or [Ask Different Meta](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/)  (cont'd)

Comment: (since that's where expertise is concentrated for interacting with SE sites using an iOS device).  If the solution isn't an out-of-the-box SE feature but can be done with some technical intervention or supplemental software, either of the site-specific Metas might be better.  But it probably doesn't make a lot of difference which one you post at.  It's already here.  I'd give it a few days.  If you don't get a response, you could close this and repost on either of the other two Meta sites.

Comment: Thanks for the insights. Just one stupid question, what do you mean by SU? Isn't it apple.stackexchange.com called Ask Different (hence AD instead of SU)?

Comment: SU is Super User.  You can pick from Meta SE, Meta SU, or Ask Different Meta (I didn't abbreviate that one since it wasn't mentioned before).

Comment: Oh, I had read that aeons ago (SOFU: SO, SF, SU), but hadn't it fresh in my head.

Comment: The iOS client, it must be said, doesn't get a lot of love. You still can't search duplicates when flagging, 4 years or so after the first request for its implementation :\

Comment: I downloaded it, it's surprisingly old, but works so nicely on what it can do.